# What is Tony Stark's obsession with the number 5?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

In the movie *Iron Man*, Pepper Potts asks Tony about his social security number to which he replies just 5 and wittily skips the question. In another scene, his array of cars has been shown one of which mentions the number plate as "STARK 5" (there are others as well).

So, on a blind note, is there any significance of Tony's interest with no. 5 in particular other than the fact that he's born in May?

Comment: When you say "(there are others as well)" do you mean there are other cars or number plates (as the placement of that text implies), or do you mean there are other examples of the number 5 being used? Two examples isn't really proof of an "obsession". The bit at the end about the entry code seems like a separate (though honestly I'd say poor) question, though is there any particular reason you think there might be something to it other than a randomly selected number?

Comment: Were the other cars labelled "STARK-1", "STARK-2", etc?

Comment: BTS shot from Iron Man 3 showing a [Stark 17 license plate](http://static.autoblog.nl/images/wp2013/iron-man-3-audi-r8-tony-stark.jpg). [Stark 33](http://cdn.thewire.com/media/old_wire/img/upload/2012/05/12/avengers/lead_large.jpg) from Avengers. He's just numbering the cars.

Comment: I've seen numerous references to Tony's favourite number being eleven, not number five. It's the number of his racing car, for example.

Comment: [Stark 66](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qTvHa.jpg) from Age of Ultron. [Stark 11](http://www.ridelust.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/2864.jpg)...

Comment: If you count the amount of letters in _Tony_ and then for no reason add 1... **you get 5**!!

Comment: @Daft - Pepper Potts has five letters in her surname, coincidence?

Comment: I think it is wonderful symmetry with the question that this question currently has a score of 5 and the only answer has a score of 5.

Answer (score 8):

**There is no obsession shown with the number 5.**

Tony is clearly just numbering his cars.

[image: Stark 11]
<sup>From Iron Man 2</sup>

[image: Stark 17]
<sup>From Iron Man 3</sup>

[image: Stark 33]
<sup>From The Avengers</sup>

[image: Stark 65]
<sup>From Avengers: Age of Ultron</sup>

Comment: So the question OP should have asked is why is Iron Man obsessed with Audis?? Is it because after 4 the number 5 comes? (there are 4 rings in Audis logo)

Comment: @Cherubel Four rings in Audi logo? Audi CEO now confirmed to be the actual Mandarin.

Comment: Half life 4 confirmed?